# Weird facebook pixel code appearing at the bottom of a webpage

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms, facebook-pixel

I have a weird problem on a Wordpress wesbite that I maintain: the code *fbq('track', 'ViewContent');* appears at the very bottom of several pages that use the Ninja Forms plugin, here is an example:

https://www.smashdocs.net/subscribe-now/

I know that this code is used for Facebook pixel tracking but I don't have any related code inserted in the theme templates or as a plugin.

The weird thing is that the code cannot be found in the source code of the webpage. However, it can be seen when using the browser's element inspector.

The code appears only on pages where a Ninja Form is used - no other pages on the  website have this problem. I tested all settings of Ninja Forms and could not find anything that has an effect on this.

I've searched on the web for this problem but could not find any help. Has anyone encountered a similar issue? I'll greatly appreciate any help on this topic.

Comment: It's not entirely clear that it's Ninja Forms with the facebook pixel. I can't find any evidence of that, and I searched their plugin and the only fb references I found are the fontawesome icons they include with their plugin. The pixel used is: https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1864546283834759 and funny enough it ERRORS when js is running. Run your site with just Ninja plugin and see if the error still continues.

Comment: Thanks for checking on this, Nathaniel. I disabled now all plugins on the site except Ninja Forms and the error was still there. It looks like the problem is within the Ninja Form plugin, most probably in the fb pixel instance you found. Perhaps I'll be able to disable the pixel somehow - could you let me know in which file I can find the reference to fb? Thanks!

Comment: One other thing that might be of help - the issue does not appear when I view the form in preview mode or if I preview a draft page where the form is already added. The fb pixel text shows only when the form is live on the website.

Comment: I had a look at the plugin code and couldn't find the pixel reference (doesn't mean it's not there). You might consider another plugin as I reckon Ninja Forms is using this pixel to help in their marketing efforts, and their pixel is broken. I use Contact Form 7, it's great, simple, and you can wire up Contact Form 7 Honeypot and Google Recaptcha pretty fast too.

Comment: Only reason I'm using Ninja Forms is because I need a hook to post the data from each form field to a server - Ninja Forms provides that. Do you know if there's a way to achieve that with Contact 7? Thanks for jumping to help with this in any case - I appreciate it!

Comment: Hm, not sure Contact forms can do that though it can store the info it collects to the wp database. If I were you, contact the Ninja Forms developer and see what's up. Weird they'd have a bad FB pixel in their code that we can't eradicate!